# Не выполняется команда из mysql-клиента без явного указания базы данных

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Выполняю команду в клиенте на C#

```
INSERT INRO database.tablename (column, column2, ...) VALUES (val1,val2,...)
```

IDE вылетает с исключением: *Additional information: INSERT command denied to user*

Хотя я дал все привилегии пользователю localhost.

А вот так все работает, надо убрать имя базы:

```
INSERT INRO tablename (column, column2, ...) VALUES (val1,val2,...)
```

Вопрос, почему? Почему имя базы каким-то образом сбивает привилегии?

*Дополнение из комментариев*

В консольном клиенте mysql синтаксис подобный не запрещен, а в MySQL Workbench так и не работает без явного указания базы данных.

Comment: INRO? Как вообще у вас это работает?

Comment: Опечатался, в ручную писал, а не копипастом, в коде INTO написано

Comment: А где вы в синтаксисе INSERT увидели выбор БД? http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/INSERT.html

Comment: Может быть у вас таблица с этим именем есть в 2х БД. И в текущей БД у вас права есть, а в явно задаваемой БД прав нет

Comment: В mysql синтаксис подобный не запрещен, а в Workbench так и не работает без явного указания БД

Answer (score 1):

При корректно выставленных правах доступа на базу данных `database` оба запроса корректно выполняются и в консольном клиенте, и в MySQL Workbench. Правда в последнем редакторе нужно внимательно следить за установкой соединение из под нового пользователя. Если при создании соединения вы не указываете базу данных по умолчанию в поле **Default Schema**, возникает ситуация, описанная вами в вопросе: запрос без явной детализации имени базы данных не выполняется.

В консольном клиенте вы тоже не сможете выполнить запрос без детализации имени базы данных `database`, если явно не выбрали базу данных в момент установки соединения или при помощи команды `USE`.